# Powerbuilder get DataStore Syntax?

Tags: powerbuilder, datastore, datawindow

I have created a dynamic datastore and I need to destroy/create bitmaps during operation (invoices logo depending on the company selected)

I destroy all bitmaps with Modify and create new ones with Modify as well.

Although Modify returns empty string (OK) I cannot see any logos created (or destroyed).

The only way I am thinking of checking it is to somehw get the Datastore syntax (code) before and after the Modify clauses.

But in the manual it states that Datastores have no Syntax.

Is there any way to get the datastore code/objects?

Thank you

Comment: You cannot see anything in a 'datastore' in PB, do you mean a 'datawindow'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use Describe to get the syntax:

lds.Describe("DataWindow.Syntax")

Here's a quick test:

```
datastore lds
lds = create datastore
lds.dataobject = 'd_emp'
clipboard(lds.Describe("DataWindow.Syntax"))
destroy lds
```